# Expanded /boot - now how do I get the "skipped" pi 4 support back?

Tags: boot, pi-4

I have a Pi 4 that has a relatively old card in it, so it had the "small" /boot partition. I noticed the message recently

```
You do not have enough space in /boot to install this package.
Skipping Pi 4 support
```

So I decided to buy a new card, create the proper sized partitions and rsync everything over. That's in progress now. Once that's done, how can I "redo" the upgrade that skipped pi 4 support and have it do the right thing?

Comment: apt upgrade again should do it

Comment: apt-get upgrade didn't seem to do anything new.

Comment: How did you ever boot the pi4 with such an old image in the first place!!!

Comment: I've been updating and upgrading all along. The stuff on the card isn't old. Just the partition table.

Comment: Oh - raspberry pi don't recommend upgrading major releases - though, to be fair, I've gonce from wheezy to jessie to stretch to buster on my first pi without ever having an issue - it takes planning, like expanding the boot partition BEFORE upgrading to whichever version had the bigger partition - it's still odd that you ever ran this image without pi 4 support on a pi 4 - I wonder if `apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-missing` would help (never broken apt myself, so ...)

Comment: Nope. that doesn't do anything. The apt system isn't broken, so far as I can tell. It just skipped over whatever package that was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears

```
apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader\* raspberrypi-kernel\*
```

is the solution.